# Store: who can access "Settings?"

Tags: expresso-store, add-on, module, addons

As a member of `Super Admins`, I can access Store's Settings:

[image]

I created a new group based on an existing on `Super Admins` and added a registered a user under it. When I tried to access Store's Settings, I get this:

[image]

Any idea what's going on? Why can't another Member Group access Store's Settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to login with your super admin account and go to the settings panel. From there you will need to navigate to the security panel. You should see your member group on the right hand side and you will need to check the boxes for the permissions you want to grant to that member group. (as seen in the picture below)

[image]